# What is the largest six-digit number with an odd number of positive factors?

Tags: contest-math, factoring, square-numbers

What is the largest six-digit number with an odd number of positive factors?

So I know the number must be a perfect square, but how do I know six-digit number perfect squares? I'm pretty sure there's a much easier way to solve/approach this problem.

The answer's supposed to be 998,001.

Comment: You probably mean "divisors" not "factors", e.g. the (positive) divisors of $12$ are $1,2,3,4,6,12$, and the (prime) factors are $2$, $2$ and $3$

Comment: $$\lfloor{\sqrt{999999}}\rfloor=999$$

Comment: @vrugtehagel: I'd say that a non-prime factor is still a factor.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It is not standard English math usage to treat the word "factor" to mean "prime factor."

Comment: Hi vrugtehagel, well, I wouldn't know because that's what the original problem asked me... And aren't factors and divisors the same thing? (Factors don't have to be prime factors do they?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first seven-digit square is $1000^2$. Thus the last six-digit square is $999^2=998001$.